# indexOf keeps returning -1. super stuck

Tags: java, android

I've initialized all the variables correctly, but it keeps returning -1.

```
private void RandomCard(int spreadname, int spreadposition) {
    try {
        SecureRandom rand = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        Collections.shuffle(list_unusedCards, rand);

        Random ranNum = new Random();
        int numUnusedCards = list_unusedCards.size();
        int pickedCard = ranNum.nextInt(numUnusedCards);

        str_cardName = list_unusedCards.get(pickedCard).GetName();
        str_cardDesc = list_unusedCards.get(pickedCard).GetDescription();
        str_imageName = list_unusedCards.get(pickedCard).GetImageName();

        String str_spreadPos = Integer.toString(spreadposition);

        cl_chosenCards = new CardList(str_cardName, str_cardDesc, str_deckChosen, str_imageName, str_spreadPos);
        list_chosenCards.add(cl_chosenCards);

        String btnPos = list_chosenCards.get(0).GetButtonPosition(); //GetButtonPosition returns value of str_spreadPos
        int int_index = list_chosenCards.indexOf(str_spreadPos);

        tv_test0.setText(str_cardName);
        tv_test1.setText(str_cardDesc);

        //tv_test2.setText("spread pos: " + str_spreadPos);             //WORKS
        //tv_test2.setText("button pos: " + btnPos);                    //WORKS
        //tv_test2.setText("index: " + int_index);                      //DOESN'T WORK, RETURNS -1
```

For the last 3 lines of code that I commented out, I've been testing those to see if the variables are being assigned correctly and if they exist inside the list. They're not null and they return the correct value. But for some reason the 3rd one keeps returning -1.

Comment: Probably because `list_chosenCards` contains `CardList` instances, while `str_spreadPos` is a `String` (and not a `CardList`).

Comment: i think i see what you're saying. in here, indexOf is supposed to return the index of a CardList element, but I'm trying to get the index of str_spreadPos which is a String element. basically what you said, lol.

Comment: i see the problem here. ive been trying to make indexOf work in a way that it doesn't work.